# How to use data from Api in ts files in ionic

Tags: html, angular, api, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to know how to can use data got from an API in the same ts file. I am able to use this data and display it in the HTML using this code.

```js
loadAppInfo() {

  this.http.get('Here goes my url')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.AppInfo = data.records;
    console.log(data.records);
  },err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

```html
<ion-option *ngFor="let data of AppInfo">{{ data.AppName }}</ion-option>
```

with this code, I can show data in HTML without any problems. But I want to set this single data to a variable in my ts file and then use it.

Is it possible?

This is how the data looks like after printing AppInfo in the console.
[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6PWL.jpg)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Um don't you do just that, isn't AppInfo a variable inside your ts file?

Comment: Yes I have AppInfo as a variable in my file, but I get undefined when I do console.log

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to call a method inside the subscribe. So when this method will be called, you'll be sure the data is filled:

```
loadAppInfo() {

  this.http.get('Here goes my url')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.AppInfo = data.records;
    this.AppName = this.AppInfo.AppName; // add "public AppName;" declaration in your class
    console.log(data.records);
    this.computeWithFilledData();
  },err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

computeWithFilledData() {
    // use this.AppInfo here
}
```

Comment: Yes, this method will be called but when I run " console.log(this.AppInfo); " I get " undefined " as an output.

Comment: where do you run this console.log ? If you run it into computeWithFilledData(), it shouldn't be undefined...

Comment: Yes, you are right it is not undefined when I run it in the method, but how can I access the single value from this?

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? What do you mean by "access the single value from this" ?

Comment: I mean AppInfo  is an object and it has other values like AboutText, AboutTitle, AppName etc. so for example how do I get to the value AppName in AppInfo ?

Comment: You can declare another variable AppName and define it in the subscription.